Errors in plot Time Series Data Prediction Results
A model was created to forecast time series data. I want to draw the result of the prediction using the plot described in the window class, but an error occurs.
The following is the error.
    plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\okuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\okuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5983, in raise_from_not_ok_stat
us
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}
} Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

The following is the plot part of the window class.
    def plot(self, model=None, plot_col="turb2_mg_L", max_subplots=1):
        inputs, labels = self.sample_batch  
        
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
        max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
        
        for n in range(max_n):
            plt.subplot(3, 1, n+1)
            plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} ')
            plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
                     label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

            if self.label_columns:
              label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
            else:
              label_col_index = plot_col_index

            if label_col_index is None:
              continue

            plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                        edgecolors='k', marker='s', label='Labels', c='green', s=64)
            if model is not None:
              predictions = model(inputs)
              plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                          marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                          c='red', s=64)

            if n == 0:
              plt.legend()

        plt.xlabel('Time(m)')


Welcome to stack overflow! The traceback tells you that predictions has not the expected shape. There are reports of similar "unexpected shapes" (e.g. this keras issue). What is the shape of predictions? You can find that out by placing print(predictions.shape) after getting it from model(inputs).

@ChristianKarcher Thank you for your comment. I solved problem by myself. It is possible to plot by changing the detention of predictions to two detentions.
